# Different arguments to array of callbacks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Consider I have four functions:

```
function first() {
  console.log("This is the first function");
}

function second() {
  console.log("This is the second function");
}

function third() {
  console.log("This is the third function");
}

function fourth(name) {
  console.log("This is the fourth function " + name);
}
```

I am trying to pass the above list of functions to a function:

```
var list_of_functions = [first, second, third, fourth];
executeFunctions(list_of_functions);
```

This is the `executeFunction`:

```
function executeFunctions(list_of_functions) {
  console.log("inside new executeFunctions");
  list_of_functions.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry();
  });
}
```

How do I pass the name argument for my `fourth` function in the array itself ? Is there any way to do this ?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
var list_of_functions = [first, second, third, fourth("Mike")];
```

Obviously, the above statement is wrong. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You want `[first, second, third, function(){ fourth("Mike"); }]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
var list_of_functions = [first, second, third, fourth.bind(this, "Mike")];
```

The first argument of `bind` is what you want `this` to be inside the `fourth` function (can be `this`, `null`, or any other object).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with another function

```
var list_of_functions = [first, second, third, function(){return fourth('Mike');}];
```